# How do I use kubernetes volumeMounts: mountPath and hostPath in helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nfs

I understand volumeMounts: mountPath and hostPath in kubernetes are connected by there name in kubernetes. How can I do the same with helm charts ?  Are there any simple examples or readme docs ?

I am trying to use nfs mounts to run containers and package it as an application using helm charts.
Thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `hostPath` at all (with limited exceptions usually involving DaemonSets); but beyond that, the Kubernetes YAML structures can be used as-is in a Helm chart.  Is there a specific issue you're encountering?

Comment: I am trying to convert an existing Linux application with several automounts to run on a container. I am able to create simple yaml file with mountpath and hostpath to run a pod. Now that I can run a pod I am trying to package it for a team to use it using helm. Are you saying I can use nfs mounts in helm charts with out using hostpath?

Comment: Yes, you can directly mount an [`nfs` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs).

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at bitnami/postgresql chart. They make use of statefulset and have a template for persistant volumes. In your case you should search for nfs csi provider in addition.